# Horizontal scaling of text using CSS

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, font-size

For our site we have selected Font stack comprising of Geneva (Mac font) and Tahoma (Win font) with Arial and Helvetica as back-up. Ideally we want Geneva (widest of all), Tahoma, Helvetica and Arial all to occupy similar space per x number of words (by adjusting horizontal spacing). Say 110% Tahoma is like 100% Geneva.

`Font stack- Geneva > Tahoma > Helvetica> Arial > sans`

Is there a better way to do this? Are there any issues with this type of approach like browser support? And if this is it then to how to go about implementing it in CSS?

Basically we've done this horizontal scaling in Photoshop/Illustrator - want to implement the same for the site as text. I guess it should be quite commonly done, but having searched long - I haven't been able to any current resource which solves the problem - 2-3 years old results don't have any solution. Being new to the site - m not allowed to post image of screenshot of photoshop - still here for reference: http://sunriseondarkhorizons.blogspot.com/2011/12/screenshot.html

PS Verdana is bit too wide to contemplate - although it is closer to Geneva space wise.

Thanks

Comment: why not include the font you need with @font-face? i think it's the only way to have full cross platform control...

Comment: Good suggestion @ptriek ! You should have make your comment a real answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only tool you have is the letter-spacing CSS attribute that increases or decreases the space between characters in a text.

```
h1 {letter-spacing:2px}
```

AFAIK there is no problem with cross-browser compatibility.

But there is a problem with figuring out when to "activate" this attribute. Since you can't know which Font the client will use beforehand, there needs to be some kind of logic/selector that decides if the letter-spacing rule should be applied.

I do not believe there is a CSS way to doing this.

What you might be able to pull off though is using JavaScript to figure our if the letter-spacing should be enlarged: Create a

element with a pre-set word like "test". Using JavaScript you can then check the width of the element against a list of pre-calculated values of the lengths of such a

for your different fonts. Depending on the outcome you add or remove the letter-spacing attribute.

It is a tricky/hacky solution, but it is the best I can come up with sorry.

Ah! Found something:

[Font Detector](http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/)